# I can not color a mesh in Max Creation Graph for 3ds max 2023

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I create a sphere.  Then create a Max Creation Graph that:

Modifier: Mesh  ->  Color Mesh  ->  Output: Modifier

I also put into the Color Mesh a vector [1,1,1] for the color

It does not change the color of the sphere.  I can swap in a Twist for the Color Mesh and with the extra inputs on that it does twist up the sphere.  But I can not get it to change colors.

Wondering if I skipped a step?  Or need to prep the sphere some way?  I did change it into a mesh and also tried adding a material to it.

Thanks if anyone has any clues!